# How to obtain spring bean objects in the idea plugin

Tags: intellij-idea

How to obtain spring bean objects in the idea plugin

I want to obtain objects from Spring in the idea plugin and be able to call them

Comment: Please provide more details about what you are trying to do. Which idea plugin? And call them from where?

Comment: I want to get the spring bean object of the project in the intelij idea plug-in, and call the method of this object in the plug-in. Can this be achieved through reflection

Comment: Or how to add a local jar to the project as a dependency? I don't want to introduce it through Maven or Gradle, only through the API provided by the plugin

Comment: what plugin do you mean?

Comment: I developed it myself

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that detail.

Comment: Where don't you understand

Comment: I think you will have to compile the code of the project and then call it.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about. I'm developing a plugin that retrieves all the object names in Spring and displays them, that's all

Comment: I'd recommend you raise this issue at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development to discuss it with the IDEA team directly

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the details that you just posted in comments. You say in your original question that you want to "call them". This implies that you need to compile the code that you want to call. On the other hand, your comment states that you want to "retrieve all the object names". This is something very different than your original question. Please edit your question to include more details and explain what you actually are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have another question, how can I add the java `-D` parameter to the project startup in the plugin